SQL query left join with sum,group by and order by in MS Access
I'm trying to execute a SQL query with a left join with sum, group by and order by clauses in MS Access.
But the result is not correct - perhaps the SQL code I am using is wrong.
Table Expense
ID  DATE        INVONO      TRANSACTION TOTEXP
----------------------------------------------
1   29-08-2024  EXP-1001    EXPENSE 25000
2   30-08-2024  EXP-1002    EXPENSE 25000
3   29-09-2024  EXP-1003    EXPENSE 30000
5   29-09-2024  EXP-1004    EXPENSE 30000

Table Invoice
DATE        INVONO      TRANSACTION    TOTPRP   TOTPRS  PAYMENT
---------------------------------------------------------------
29-08-2024  SALES-1000  SALES           100000  150000  150000
30-08-2024  SALES-1001  SALES           300000  350000  350000
29-09-2024  SALES-1002  SALES           200000  250000  250000
29-09-2024  SALES-1003  SALES           200000  250000  250000
30-09-2024  SALES-1004  SALES           250000  300000  
30-09-2024  SALES-1005  SALES           250000  300000  

My query:
SELECT 
    Invoice.Date AS [DATE],
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) AS TOTPRP, 
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) AS TOTPRS, 
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) AS PAYMENT, 
    SUM(Expense.Totexp) AS TOTEXP, 
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) - SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) AS TOTRESULT,
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) - SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) AS TOTOUTSTANDING,
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) - (SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) + SUM(Expense.TotEXP)) AS TOTPROFITNET
FROM 
    Invoice 
LEFT JOIN 
    Expense ON Invoice.Date = Expense.Date
GROUP BY 
    Invoice.Date, Invoice.INVONO
ORDER BY 
    Invoice.Date;

Result from my SQL query:



DATE
TOTPRP
TOTPRS
PAYMENT
TOTEXP
TOTRESULT
TOTOUTSTANDING
TOTPROFITNET




29-08-2024
100000
150000
150000
25000
50000
0
25000


29-09-2024
400000
500000
500000
60000
100000
0
40000


29-09-2024
400000
500000
500000
60000
100000
0
40000


29-09-2024
300000
350000
350000
25000
50000
0
25000


29-09-2024
250000
300000


50000




29-09-2024
250000
300000


50000





Is it possible to apply the field date to a period?
Desired result



Period
TOTPRP
TOTPRS
PAYMENT
TOTEXP
TOTRESULT
TOTOUTSTANDING
TOTPROFITNET




Aug-24
400000
500000
500000
50000
100000
0
50000


Sep-24
900000
1100000
500000
60000
200000
-600000
-460000




You need to GROUP BY the date range you want to sum.
In your case, you want to sum the data per month, so you will use FORMAT(Invoice.[DATE], 'MMM-yy') to build exactly the date range you requested.
This will then be put to the column selection, to the GROUP BY clause and also to the ORDER BY clause.
The entire query will be this:
SELECT 
    FORMAT(Invoice.[DATE], 'MMM-yy') AS Period,
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) AS TOTPRP, 
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) AS TOTPRS, 
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) AS PAYMENT, 
    SUM(Expense.Totexp) AS TOTEXP, 
    SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) - SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) AS TOTRESULT,
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) - SUM(Invoice.TotPRS) AS TOTOUTSTANDING,
    SUM(Invoice.PAYMENT) - (SUM(Invoice.TotPRP) + SUM(Expense.TotEXP)) AS TOTPROFITNET
FROM 
    Invoice 
LEFT JOIN 
    Expense ON Invoice.[DATE] = Expense.[DATE]
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(Invoice.[DATE], 'MMM-yy')
ORDER BY 
    FORMAT(Invoice.[DATE], 'MMM-yy');

See this sample fiddle

WITH InvoiceSummary AS (
    SELECT 
        FORMAT(DATE, 'yy-MMM') AS Period,
        SUM(TotPRP) AS TOTPRP, 
        SUM(TotPRS) AS TOTPRS, 
        SUM(PAYMENT) AS PAYMENT
    FROM 
        Invoice 
    GROUP BY 
        FORMAT(DATE, 'yy-MMM')
),
ExpenseSummary AS (
    SELECT 
        FORMAT(DATE, 'yy-MMM') AS Period,
        SUM(TotEXP) AS TOTEXP
    FROM 
        Expense 
    GROUP BY 
        FORMAT(DATE, 'yy-MMM')
)

SELECT 
    ISNULL(i.Period, e.Period) AS Period,
    ISNULL(i.TOTPRP, 0) AS TOTPRP, 
    ISNULL(i.TOTPRS, 0) AS TOTPRS, 
    ISNULL(i.PAYMENT, 0) AS PAYMENT, 
    ISNULL(e.TOTEXP, 0) AS TOTEXP, 
    ISNULL(i.TOTPRS, 0) - ISNULL(i.TOTPRP, 0) AS TOTRESULT,
    ISNULL(i.PAYMENT, 0) - ISNULL(i.TOTPRS, 0) AS TOTOUTSTANDING,
    ISNULL(i.PAYMENT, 0) - (ISNULL(i.TOTPRP, 0) + ISNULL(e.TOTEXP, 0)) AS TOTPROFITNET
FROM 
    InvoiceSummary i
FULL OUTER JOIN 
    ExpenseSummary e ON i.Period = e.Period
ORDER BY 
    Period;

Result
| Period | TOTPRP  | TOTPRS  | PAYMENT  | TOTEXP  | TOTRESULT | TOTOUTSTANDING | TOTPROFITNET |
|--------|---------|---------|----------|---------|-----------|----------------|---------------|
| 24-Aug | 400000  | 500000  | 500000   | 50000   | 100000    | 0              | 50000         |
| 24-Sep | 900000  | 1100000 | 500000   | 60000   | 200000    | -600000        | -460000       |



@harsini , thanks for your answer but I have an error invalid sql statement  in with

I doubt MS Access support cte's.

Just redesign the SQL and Make it simple.
I implemented it on MS Access 2016. It did not accept field name [DATE] noticing that it is a reserved word. So, I made two changes in field name InvDate in invoice table and ExpDate in expense table.
Let's start the actual work.
Make two sub query(Expense and Invoice Table) for summary of the figures on period (monthly).
The query on Expenses table will be
SELECT 
    FORMAT(EXPDATE,'yyyy-MMM') AS PERIOD,
    SUM(TotExp) AS EXP FROM EXPENSE GROUP BY FORMAT(EXPDATE,'yyyy-MMM')

And the query on Invoice table will be
SELECT FORMAT(INVDATE,'yyyy-MMM') AS PERIOD, 
    SUM(TotPRP) AS TOTPRPP, 
    SUM(TotPRS) AS TOTPRSS, 
    SUM(PAYMENT) AS TOTPAY,
    SUM(TOTPRS - TotPRP) AS TOTRESULT,
    SUM(PAYMENT - TotPRS) AS TOTOUTSTANDING 
    FROM 
    INVOICE 
GROUP BY FORMAT(INVDATE,'yyyy-MMM')

Finally, to get the final result as you described these two queries will joined
SELECT  A.PERIOD, B.TOTPRPP AS TOTPRP, B.TOTPRSS AS TOTPRS,  B.TOTPAY AS PAYMENT, 
A.EXP AS ToTEXP, B.TOTRESULT, B.TOTOUTSTANDING,
 B.TOTPAY-(B.TOTPRPP+A.EXP) AS TOTPROFITNET 

FROM 

(SELECT 
    FORMAT(EXPDATE,'yyyy-MMM') AS PERIOD,
    SUM(TotExp) AS EXP FROM EXPENSE GROUP BY FORMAT(EXPDATE,'yyyy-MMM') ) A

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT FORMAT(INVDATE,'yyyy-MMM') AS PERIOD, 
    SUM(TotPRP) AS TOTPRPP, 
    SUM(TotPRS) AS TOTPRSS, 
    SUM(PAYMENT) AS TOTPAY,
    SUM(TOTPRS-TotPRP) AS TOTRESULT,
    SUM(PAYMENT) - SUM(TotPRS) AS TOTOUTSTANDING 
    FROM INVOICE GROUP BY FORMAT(INVDATE,'yyyy-MMM')) B  

ON  A.PERIOD = B.PERIOD;


On practical ground, if you want to sort the result on column [period] the format of date needs to be changed (example. 2024-Aug will be 2024-08, 2024-Sep will be 2024-09). To make this change you have to use format(InvDate,'yyyy-mm') instead of FORMAT(InvDate,'yyyy-MMM').
